# AWX Inventory File drop down in SOURCE does not allow specifying of file path

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I can't seem to specify the full path to my inventory file in 'sources' in AWX. From several screenshots I have seen, this should be possible? Any ideas of what may be causing this? The first screenshot below is mine and the second is from the tower website.

Thanks.

1. My config

[image]

2. The below image is on the tower website and clearly shows you are able to do this through the sources tab.

[image]

3. Codecommit Project configuration
   [image]

Comment: Is your `awscodecommit` project configured to get its content from an SCM ? Did you update your project at least once prior to launching the above form ?

Comment: The codecommit project is using Git and does sync the inventory successfully. The problem is, if I then include playbooks in a subdirectory in the same repository and run inventory sync, it tries to sync the entire repository inc. all playbooks. This is because the inventory source file location is /project root. So I suspect when syncing it tries to sync everything. To fix, i tried to moving the inventory file into a dedicated directory but then ran into the problem of not being able to point to the appropriate directory in the source tab per OP. I have attached a screenshot of the Project.

Comment: If by "update your project at least once prior to launching the above form" you mean syncing it, yes I have synced the project several times.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution for this so have created a separate repo for 'playbooks' and the 'inventory' to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create inventory file as .ini structure, which will show you as you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).